# Stopwatch class in c++

Tags: c++, time, time.h

I have to write a stopwatch class in c++. The way I am trying to do this is by defining a variable to save laps (named 'time') and a `bool` that I use to see if the watch is started or stopped. When entering a `char` the timer should start and set `time1`. When another char is entered the `bool` switches to `false` and sets `time2` and then prints `time2-time1`. This should be repeatable until 'n' is entered

I also am not quite sure I understand what unit of time time_t is in. In my code i get a return value of ±40 units every time i try to measure the interval of a lap, which I am guessing is the runtime of the program and not actually the time of the interval.

```
#ifndef stoppuhr_hpp
#define stoppuhr_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

class Stoppuhr{
private:
    bool running;
    clock_t time;

public:
    void pushButtonStartStop () {
        char t=0;
        running=false;
        time=0;
        std::cout << "to start/stop watch please press a key, to end 
clock type 'n' " << std::endl;
        clock_t time1=0;
        clock_t time2=0;
        std::cout << time;

        while (t!='n') {
            std::cin >> t;
            running= !running;
            if (running) {
                time1=clock();
            }
            else {
                time2=clock();
                time+=time2-time1;
                std::cout << time << std::endl;
            }
        }

    }

};

#endif /* stoppuhr_hpp */
```

Comment: In C++ you should `#include <ctime>` not time.h.  The units of `time_t` are in seconds for POSIX compliant systems.  The only guarantee by the C++ standard is that it is defined in an arithmetic type.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these functions, but when I ask Google about "time.h clock()" [the first suggestion](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) gives the answer.

Comment: It's clearly a homework problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also am not quite sure I understand what unit of time time_t is in.

The unit of time represented by `time_t` is implementation specified. Usually, it represents seconds, as specified by POSIX.

However, you don't use `time_t` anywhere in your program.

> I am guessing is the runtime of the program

I recommend not to guess, but to read documentation instead. `clock()` returns the processor time used by the program since some point in time. So deducting two timepoints returned by `clock()` will give you the processor time used between those timepoints.  The unit of `clock_t` is `1 /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC` seconds.

> i get a return value of ±40 units every time

Granularity of `clock` is implementation specified. It might be 40 units on your system. The program consumes hardly any processor time while it waits for input.

---

> I have to write a stopwatch class

Stopwatches typically measure real world time i.e. wall clock time. Measuring processor time would be futile for this task.

I recommend using `std::chrono::steady_clock::now` instead.

If you insist on using time.h, then you can use `time(nullptr)` to get the wall clock time but I don't recommend it.